# LlamaIndex Not Checking All Documents When Queried

Tags: python

I'm loading a large amount of documents into LlamaIndex and I am able to ask questions about each of these documents individually, but when it comes to asking questions about the documents overall, there are gaps in its knowledge.

An example of the document in context of real estate would be.

```
Document(
    id_=data['full_address'],
    metadata={
        "address": data['address'],
        "price": data['price'],
        "sqft": data['sqft'],
    },
    text=data['tax_history']
)
```

I am able to ask questions like "what are the tax records for address 123 foo street" and get reliable responses, but I am unable to ask questions like "what is the median house price on foo street" I begin to notice gaps in the data. Say there are 15 houses on that street, it would only grab 3 or so to perform the calculation.

My index and embedding settings are below.

```
llm = OpenAI(temperature=.5, model="gpt-4")
embed_model = OpenAIEmbedding()
prompt_helper = PromptHelper(
    context_window=4096,

    chunk_overlap_ratio=0.1,
    chunk_size_limit=None,
)
service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm=llm, chunk_size=1028, prompt_helper=prompt_helper, embed_model=embed_model)

vector_store = PineconeVectorStore(
    index_name='real-estate',
    environment='us-east1-gcp',
)

storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(vector_store=vector_store)

index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
    [],
    storage_context=storage_context,
    service_context=service_context,
)
```

I feel like I may be using the wrong tool for the job here. How do I make LlamaIndex query through all (or more of) the documents to give an answer? or is there a better tool for this job?

Comment: that my help : https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/optimizing/production_rag.html#structured-retrieval-for-larger-document-sets

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `similarity_top_k` to a larger number? By default it is probably only fetching 2 or 3 chunks, which would why it doesn't know about every house.

Longer term you might want to look into turning the structured data you've got into a structured store like a database, and then using a text-to-SQL tool to run queries like sums and averages. LLMs are not very good at math :-)

Comment: I have tried that, up to a quite large number. And yea the median question was really just an example, something more meaningful would be like, "which house on X street sold for the most." if it only looks at a few of the documents, then it may or may not return the largest of the whole data set. Should i perhaps use a seperate document that kind of summarizes each street? Thanks!

Comment: If I were in your position I'd use the LLM to extract the salient facts into a SQL database and get text-to-SQL to answer questions, the database isn't going to have top-k problems like RAG would.